# get_version() PyInstaller Syntax Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

I am running the latest version of python (3.3.2 32bit Intel win32) and have installed PyInstaller to compile my `*.py` files to `*.exe` executables. I compile my files via the Windows CMD (`cmd.exe`), but have recieved an error:

```
G:\PyInstaller>python pyinstaller.py prog.py
File "pyinstaller.py", line 73
print get_version()
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any thoughts of why this is error is occurring? Both of the programs have installed correctly without any problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the pyinstaller [github page](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller) and [official site](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) Python 3 is not yet supported.

Also see the trac [issue](http://www.pyinstaller.org/ticket/601) relevant to your error and the [issue](http://www.pyinstaller.org/ticket/85) on supporting Python 3.

Comment: Yup, should work with 2.7: `Multiversion: works under any version of Python from 2.3 up to 2.7.`

Comment: Thank you very much will accept as answer ASAP once timer wears off.

Comment: Also, while I'm at it, is there any major differences between Python 2.7 and Python 3.x.x?

Comment: @CheesyBacon, there are some major differences. `print` being a function is an important one. 2to3 will fix/translate many cases however sometimes the code needs to be reworked a little.

Comment: @gnibbler Is the command `python` supposed to work in the command prompt in windows?

Comment: @CheesyBacon, that would depend whether you've added the installation directory to your path

Comment: @CheesyBacon here's some info on differences between 2 and 3 branches and porting: http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3.

Comment: Try to use full path to `python` like `C:\Python27\python.exe`.

Comment: @alecxe Ah. so enter `Path\To\Python.exe pyinstaller.py prog.py` in the cmd?

Comment: OK, thanks for helping, I was really desperate to get these done. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This particular error is because `print` is a function in Python3, so trying to use it as a statement is a SyntaxError