# Troubles Installing gdsCAD

Tags: python, cad

I tried to install gdsCAD using the anaconda prompt : https://pypi.org/project/gdsCAD/

But I got the error:

```
Collecting gdsCAD
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/54/60b48ee74d5ba364c4aaaf6a73e0d47274a501aafd3d64b04ce7b03b40f9/gdsCAD-0.4.5.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\EPFL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-59twocd7\gdsCAD\setup.py", line 4, in <module>
        from git_version import sdist, get_version
      File "C:\Users\EPFL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-59twocd7\gdsCAD\git_version.py", line 107
        print get_version()
                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\EPFL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-59twocd7\gdsCAD\
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because you are trying to use Python 3 with gdsCAD, which it is not compatible with.  See for instance [the same error occurring here for the same reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399029/get-version-pyinstaller-syntax-error).

If you'd like an alternative, you could consider trying out [PHIDL](https://github.com/amccaugh/phidl) (full disclosure: I am the lead developer), which is a simplified GDS geometry / CAD python module we've been working on for the last two years (built as a robust and simplified frontend to gdspy).

Comment: I left out the specific reason for the error:  The print statement changed from Python 2 (print 'hello') to Python 3 (print('hello')).  For Python 3 it should read print(get_version())

Answer (score 0):

As answered by others, you seem to install it for Python 3.0. You can follow the below steps to install it with Python 3.x

1. Clone the repo from https://github.com/hohlraum/gdsCAD.git
2. Checkout to the remote branch named '2and3'. git branch -r will show this branch.
3. Then go to repo that directory and do python setup.py install